# Compactification of a straight line

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, mathematical-physics

Like in the case of mapping a infinite-plane to a sphere (Riemann Sphere), I can understand, that I can map the infinite line ($-\infty,\infty$) to a circle.

Secondly, I can also map a finite line segment (of length $L$) onto a circle (of radius $r$) which is even more straightforward by setting say, $2\pi r = L$. But this kind of mapping can't compactify the line segment in the case when $\lim L \rightarrow \infty $.

I would like to know if there can be a map to compactify the semi-infinite line $(0,\infty)$. Or if not is there a way of proving that there can exist no such maps ?

Comment: The one-point compactifications of $(-\infty, \infty)$, $(0, \infty)$, and $(a, b)$ are all the same as they are homeomorphic.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese : I am sorry, am from a physics background, what is one-point compactification ?

Comment: I believe this is what you are calling a compactification. Given a (locally compact, Hausdorff) topological space $X$, there exists a compact topological space $\hat{X}$ obtained from $X$ by adding one-point; the space $\hat{X}$ is called the one-point compactification of $X$. In the case where $X$ is an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$, its one-point compactification $\hat{X}$ is a circle.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese : Can you please elaborate on the homeomorphic nature of the map !

Comment: Which map are you referring to? I have not mentioned any maps.

Comment: @user35952 There is a difference between asking whether the compactification of $(0,\infty)$ is homeomorphic to that of $\mathbb{R}$, and asking someone to produce such a homeomorphism.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese : As I already told, I am sorry for the limited knowledge in the subject. I am referring to the compactification as a map (like an algebraic relation in the case of plane and riemann sphere). I just wish to know how would I go about, in principle constructing this compactification, say in a geometric or algebraic, viz. relating the coordinates of line to that of the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to construct a homeomorphism between $(0,\infty)$ and $S^1 - \{(0,1)\}$ which can easily be extended to the compactification $(0,\infty)\cup \{p\}$ and $S^1$.

1. Let $f:(0,\infty) \to (-1,1)$ be the map $f(x) = \frac{2}{x+1} -1$.  $f$ is clearly injective, continuous and if $r \in (-1,1)$ then $x = \frac{2}{r+1}-1 \in (0,\infty)$ will map to $r$.
2. Now define the map $g:(-1,1) \to S^1/ \{(0,1)\}$ given by $g(x) = (2x\sqrt{1-x^2}, 2x^2 - 1)$.
3. Take their composition $h = g\circ f$.

We can therefore use the map $h:(0,\infty)\cup \{p\} \to S^1$

$$
h(x) \;\; =\;\; \begin{cases}
g(f(x)), & \text{if} \; x \in (0,\infty) \\
(0,1), & \text{if} \; x=p
\end{cases}.
$$

Comment: +1 for the map ! I think I will take some time to see physically what is going behind in this map ! Thank you !

Comment: @user35952 Ok, It's fixed now.  To give some intuition behind it, $f$ flips and shrinks $(0,\infty)$ down to $(-1,1)$ and then $(-1,1)$ is curved so that it takes up the whole circle less the top point $(0,1)$.